# Module for OneSignal for Appcelerator

Tags: module, push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, onesignal

Recently I found [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) platform we can send push notifications for free, their service is really complete. I'm trying to implement it on Appcelerator but I can't find any module for Appcelerator.

Did anyone already use their services on Appcelerator? How can I create a module for OneSignal for appcelerator I am a newbie with all of this :/

Answer (score 1):

You can find guides on Appcelerator module development here:

- [Android_Module_Development_Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide)
- [iOS_Module_Development_Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide)